# Superposition principle and wave interference

Tags: waves, interference, superposition

I am learning superposition principle and that sinusoidal waves(solutions to linear wave equations) added algebraically create the solution of the new wave created by the original two waves. I understand the superposition principle that the linear combination of two solutions is also a solution to the linear wave pde. However, I am having difficulty understanding why the addition of the two solutions become precisely the solution created by interference. In other words, just because the two wave solutions $A\sin kx$ and $A\cos kx$ can be added to create a wave solution that satisfies the wave equation doesn't seem to guarantee that it is precisely the solution to the wave that actually is created when we put these two waves together experimentically. I believe this can be explained with the traveling of energy but am having trouble putting this into equations. None of the textbooks I have seen explain this part in detail and just say that "Due to superposition we can add the wave solutions together".

As an elaboration/second question, this may be a bit broad but how would we calculate interference for waves that don't satisfy superposition(a.k.a. non-linear waves)? I have no idea how to approach this question due to the first question - there is no logical connection between superposition and the actual solution to interference.

Comment: It becomes clearer when you consider more than just one dimension. Interference fringes appear when waves propagating is slightly different directions overlap.

Comment: That's not quite what I am curious about. I am having difficulty understanding the mathematical logic behind why we can use superposition to calculate the interference fringes.

Comment: Waves have positive and negative regions. When they overlap they would sometimes add up to produce constructive interference and other times they cancel giving destructive interference. Note sure what you are referring to by "mathematical logic"?

Comment: Well is there any logic that explains why the wave solutions $f_1$ and $f_2$ added create $f_1+f_2$ when we actually experiment with the two waves? It seems that superposition principle only guarantees that this is a **possible** solution to the wave equation.

Comment: "doesn't seem to guarantee that it is precisely the solution to the wave that actually is created when we put these two waves together experimentically" - well, of course it doesn't. That's *why* you have experiments and experimental measurements: so that you can check if the model is right, or how approximate it is - or if it is wrong. There *is no* mathematical logic that will 100% prove it to you that your theoretical idea matches reality. You have to gain confidence by doing bunch of experimental checks over time. This is true in all of science.

Comment: Ah, I understand what you are saying. It still seems to surprise me a little that none of the textbooks explain that further experiment is required to "prove" that superposition implies interference and cannot be done with just math. The explanation provided in the book was quite unintuitive for me.

Comment: Yeah, textbooks for some reason aren't that good at communicating how the scientific method works, but the idea is - you have a theoretical framework, which is just a set of concepts and ideas and equations that describe some phenomenon of interest, expressed in a way that allows you to make testable predictions ("if I throw a ball this hard, it will fall there and take this long", or "if I interfere two waves, I expect to see this pattern", or even a bit more vague "I expect fossils not to appear out of order in unperturbed sediments"). Then experiment and observation test those predictions.

Comment: Now, as you might have noticed, different sciences are able to do this to a greater or a lesser degree depending on the nature of their problem domain and the tools (technological, conceptual, mathematical) they have at their disposal - so the level of confidence that can be established also varies across disciplines (compare, for example, physics, geology, biology, social sciences, history; I left out math because it sort of operates in a domain of its own - and this allows it to have things like absolute proofs).